# How to say that something is overrated, overhyped

Tags: words

I lack in ways to express the idea that something is overhyped, overrated, has an overestimated value.

What I’d like to say is that a restaurant/place/book/movie/idea is advertised or promoted to excess, that even though it’s not *that* bad, it does not live up to its legend.

The translation should not be too ‘negative’ because when you say that a movie was overhyped it does not necessarily imply that it is a bad movie; it could even be a pretty OK movie depending on the context.

I know 過大評価 (an overestimation) so I thought of 過大評価される, but can it be used in this context? My gut feeling is that this word is meant to be used in such sentences as *I overestimated the value of this car* or something like this. And this word is a bit long anyway.

In case some exemple sentences are required, here are some:

> 名古屋城 is a nice castle indeed but it is vastly overhyped as far as I’m concerned.
>
> This is the most overrated book of the XXth century. *(Real sentence I just read in a press article.)*
>
> *No Man’s Sky* is not a bad game, but it was so overhyped that people couldn’t help but be disappointed.

Answer (score 3):

過大評価 is a very common phrase, and you can safely use it in casual conversations despite its length. You can use it with your three examples. You can also use 持ち上げる ("to raise; to hype") and say 持ち上げられすぎている, 過度に持ち上げられている, etc.

In your *No Man's Sky* example, you are referring to the expectation prior to the release rather than the post-release evaluation. In case you don't feel 評価 is the best word, you can say 期待されすぎた, 過度に期待された, or 期待が高すぎた instead.

Answer (score 0):

For alternative words/phrases of the word of 過大評価 'overrated/hyped'

Casual

行き過ぎ/言い過ぎ/やり過ぎ/盛りすぎ/褒めすぎ じゃない？ (often with ちょっと)

話を盛る/水増しする/大袈裟に言う/褒めちぎる *use with passive/present progressive form*

Indirect or cynic,

飾りが多い/話が上手いね/よく出来てるね

Formal

(少し)買いかぶっている

I think still many other ways.